# Convert input[type=file] to Base64 before submitting to HomeController

Tags: asp.net, image, input, tobase64string

How can I convert 5 separate inputs shown below:

```
<form action="uploadImages" method="post" id="frm">
     <input name="Img1" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
     <input name="Img2" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
     <input name="Img3" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
     <input name="Img4" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
     <input name="Img5" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" class="UserSubmit" />
</form>
```

To Base64 string before it gets sent to the HomeController.

the file types will only be images. (png/jpg).

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The Controller can do this easily. But if you really need to then convert them using some sort of jQuery code and put the converted images in an input type=text

Comment: I get the error message 'Maximum request length exceeded' when doing it using the method you mentioned, and i already tried increasing the limits in the web.config file with no changes taking effect, so i am looking for alternative ways of doing it

Comment: Nervermind we facken fixed it, you literally helped fokol.

Comment: sorry for crass language, I am a afrikaaner boet and very excited, We just needed to change the web.config file in Framework version 4